# Email notification if cron job fails?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

We are running a cron job on our website and which is doing very important work on our server with database. If that cron job fails we need to be notified so that we'll know that the work it needs to do is not done.
Any way to do it if cron doesn't runs.
Server already sends an email as soon as that cron runs but we can't have tons of emails everyday and if cron runs every 5 minutes we won't be able to track an email if it doesn't runs, that's why want to be able to track the failure of cron.

Comment: What does the cron job do?

Comment: exactly how would you check if cron isn't running? you'd need a scheduled job, which means a cron job.. but oops, cron isn't running. If you mean detect if the innards of the job fail, then put in a `If (!success) { send notice }` type logic block.

Comment: There is no need of separate monitoring of cron. On basis of return code, you can set email notification.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Normally you would set `MAILTO` in your crontab to notify you of any error running the job - `MAILTO=me@here.com`. Of course, this assumes that your server has email capability.

Comment: Dan I can't tell you what that cron job for some reason I can't explain everything but it sets some fields in database which are very important to our system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could designate a secondary computer as a "listener". Set up a database (on either machine) and have the cron job write a row to that database when it starts (including a date-stamp). Then schedule another cron job on the secondary machine which periodically checks this database to see when the last time the primary cron job ran. If it's been more than X amount of time then the secondary cron job would send an email to you to notify you that the primary script never ran.

Note: you could also just use a single file that both machines have write-access to, and record the last-run timestamp in there, but the nice thing about the database approach is that is serves as a query-able log of all cron activity.

Comment: Thanks I think this should work I can check the timestamp of cron last ran and if a timestamp is missing means cron didn't ran.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers offer the ability to send an email every time a CRON runs.  This is the opposite of what you're asking; but, it could provide a target email folder to monitor with a program.

Answer (score 0):

there are a handful of services which you can use to get notifications when cron scripts fail.

these generally work by setting up your cron task so that it runs, then calls the service with an identifier

for example in your crontab:

```
/path/to/very_important_script.sh && curl https://api.isitworking.info/c/SWITCH_IDENTIFIER &> /dev/null
```

If your script doesn't check in after N mins, then the monitoring service knows there is a failure and lets you know.

This is potentially more reliable than the email idea; It doesn't assume that a failing server can still send a warning mail!

full disclosure: I wrote IsItWorking.info, but there are others out there that do a similar job.